# Pop-ups within Forms c#

Tags: c#, popup

I'm working on a project and I'm creating a pop-up opened by a button using the code below.. I would like the pop-up form to be in the center of the main form. Is there any solution?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Interclasare popup= new Interclasare();
        DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            popup.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `popup` is a form, yes:

```
popup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```